# installing Xamarin on visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

[image: Error message][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJpRf.jpg)

error for installing Xamarin.Android Api Level not installed successfully.

Can any one tell me how to troubleshoot this error? Is there any way that I can install them explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the missing packages via Android SDK Manager. The manager can be opened from Visual Studio's top menu: `Tools` > `Android` > `Android SDK Manager`.

Within the manager, you can select the missing build tools and emulator images that you want to install.

[Here's](http://www.themethodology.net/2015/02/android-sdk-manager-setup-for.html?m=1) a good overview on the tool

Comment: hey there.thanks for help but when i opened Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager. i got my menu disabled.can you tell me why this happened.PFA screenshot